# IONIC Angular Spacing seems to be wrong

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have an ionic list, like below. The lines between each item form the list have a spacing to the left corner, but no one to the right.
I didn't add any styling.
Is this correct?

```
<ion-list>
    <div *ngFor="let s of getStories();">
      <ion-item>
        <ion-thumbnail>
          <img class="imgmg" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
        </ion-thumbnail>
        <ion-label class="ion-margin">
          <h2>Luke</h2>
            <h3>Your thoughts betray you</h3>
            <p>I feel the good in you, the conflict...</p>
        </ion-label>
      </ion-item>
    </div>
  </ion-list>
```

[example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1MYLh.png)

Answer (score 0):

The [the expected behaviour](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/item#slots) for ionic items is a line with padding for the start-slotted element. Add **slot="start"** to your thumbnail to have the line starting after it.

```
<ion-thumbnail slot="start">
  <img class="imgmg" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
</ion-thumbnail>
```

If you want a full line from start to bottom, you can add property lines="none" and add a border-bottom by yourself. [ion-list](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/list#properties) has a lines property too, to control which items will receive a bottom line.

[image]

Comment: But your example looks different. 
The bottom line is only under the text. Which would be fine for me. 
My example looks different.

Comment: @sascha.k I updated my answer to make it more relevant : to achieve it you will have to use a slot for your thumbnail